# How to make multiple Instances from a class move at the same time in gyame

Tags: python, class, pygame

```
import pygame, os, sys
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

RED = ( 255, 0, 0)

class WPawn():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('wpawn.png'), (100,100))

        self.move_x = 0
        self.move_y = 0

    def event_handler(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == K_UP:
                   self.move_y = -100
               if event.key == K_DOWN:
                   self.move_y = 100

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key in (K_UP, K_DOWN):
                    self.move_y = 0


    def update(self, screen):
        self.y = self.y + self.move_y

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        screen_width = 900
        screen_height = 900
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption ("Chess Project")        

        self.pawn1 = WPawn(50,650)
        self.pawn2 = WPawn(150,650)
        self.pawn3 = WPawn(250,650)
        self.pawn4 = WPawn(350,650)
        self.pawn5 = WPawn(450,650)
        self.pawn6 = WPawn(550,650)
        self.pawn7 = WPawn(650,650)
        self.pawn8 = WPawn(750,650)    

    def play(self):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()


        RUNNING = True
        while RUNNING:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

            clock.tick(30)

            self.pawn1.event_handler()
            self.pawn2.event_handler()
            self.pawn3.event_handler()
            self.pawn4.event_handler()
            self.pawn5.event_handler()
            self.pawn6.event_handler()
            self.pawn7.event_handler()
            self.pawn8.event_handler()

            self.pawn1.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn2.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn3.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn4.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn5.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn6.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn7.update(self.screen)
            self.pawn8.update(self.screen)

            self.screen.fill(RED)

            self.pawn1.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn2.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn3.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn4.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn5.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn6.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn7.draw(self.screen)
            self.pawn8.draw(self.screen)

            pygame.display.update()

Game().play()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: All of the instances (pawns) should inherit the move function from the class but only the first pawn that have been drawn moves and the rest of them stay stationary when the up/down button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KEY_UP` event (or whatever) is consumed when you process it.  So whichever `WPawn` class gets the event first will move.

Generally an event-driven program has only *one* event loop.

It may be easier to make this work by handling the event processing outside of the game objects.  Have the single event loop handle record the key press, then move each `WPawn` that you wish to be moved.

Perhaps something like:

```
event = pygame.event.get()
if event.type == K_DOWN:
    foreach pawn in all_pawns:
        pawn.moveDown()
elif event.type == K_UP:
    foreach pawn in all_pawns:
        pawn.moveUp()
```